# Is there an IDE in Linux that also makes the makefile so that you can the make command from the command line?

Tags: command-line, c++, make, ide

So this isn't a question about who has a favorite IDE. This question is about facts and **NOT opinions**. Either the IDE mentioned in the answer has this ability or it doesn't.

Which (if any) C++ IDEs make a makefile with the project? So that if I wanted to work outside of the IDE itself, I could just work with a simple text editor and the command line.

I have used Visual Studio in Windows. I have also used a text editor (Sublime Text 3) and the command line in Linux. I am looking for this because I am tired of typing/copying/pasting everything in Linux and would like to use the features provided by IDE (such as templates). At the same time some of the projects that I would have to turn into school are graded automatically. It works by turning in the makefile and the header/source files and it runs the make command.

I would also like to not have to make the makefiles anymore. So I would like for the IDE to create that. So if I have a program named HelloWorld, I would like to build it in the IDE as I would in Visual Studio and when needed go to the project location in the command line and be able to type `make` and then run the program `./HelloWorld`

Answer (score 0):

CodeLight is an IDE on Linux that allows you to run the `make` command from the command line. So, using this I can utilize both ways to develop.